# ORA-00913 too many values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have this query

```
INSERT INTO hist_museum (SELECT * from of_owner.museum al
                                JOIN (SELECT vd.city_data_id 
                                        FROM of_owner.city_data vd 
                                        WHERE gps_full_date < add_months(SYSDATE,-12)) vd
                                    ON al.city_data_id = VD.city_data_id);
```

and the tables hist_museum and museum are exactly the same, but even that I got this error:

```
Error(10,19): PL/SQL: ORA-00913: demasiados valores
```

Comment: You may intend `al.*`, but you should be including the list of columns both in the `select` and the `insert`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, please convert to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With "select * from al JOIN ..." you get all values from al and your joined subrequest vd. What you want is

```
INSERT INTO hist_museum (SELECT al.* from of_owner.museum al
                            JOIN (SELECT vd.city_data_id 
                                    FROM of_owner.city_data vd 
                                    WHERE gps_full_date < add_months(SYSDATE,-12)) vd
                                ON al.city_data_id = VD.city_data_id);
```

Answer (score 3):

The best-practice when doing an `insert` is to list the columns explicitly:

```
INSERT INTO hist_museum(col1, col2, . . . )
     SELECT col1, col2, . . .
     FROM of_owner.museum al JOIN
          of_owner.city_data vd 
          ON al.city_data_id = VD.city_data_id
     WHERE gps_full_date < add_months(SYSDATE, -12);
```

Of course, the columns in the `SELECT`, should be qualified with the table name.

In addition, the subquery is unnecessary.  There is no reason to write a subquery just to filer data.