# INSERT INTO with different number of colums

Tags: sql, oracle, select, left-join, sql-insert

I want to insert a row from table A (NAG) into table B (Kunde).

Table NAG has only 4 columns and table Kunde has 13 columns. Since there is a difference of the columns' number, I get always an error: ora-00913 too many values.

The query I used are:

```
INSERT INTO kunde
SELECT * FROM NAG
left outer join kunde ON NAG.adrnr = kunde.adrnr
WHERE kunde.adrnr IS NULL
```

adrnr is the customer ID. And I'm using SQLTools 1.8b38 if that helps.
Can anyone please help me to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Instead of `SELECT *` (which selects 17 columns, 4 from nag and 13 from kunde) you need to select just the 13 columns you want to insert.

Comment: the 4 columns I want to insert from NAG tables are: adrnr, tmstmp, matchcode, Art.
I want to insert them into Kunde Table which has 13 columns.

I tried this query: INSERT INTO kunde
SELECT adrnr, tmstmp, matchcode, Art FROM NAG
left outer join kunde ON NAG.adrnr = kunde.adrnr
WHERE kunde.adrnr IS NULL.

But i still get an error: ORA-00918 column not clearly defined

Comment: Please edit and add the information about the NAG table definition to your Question. And this SQL you tried. Do not provide clarifications in comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORA-00913 too many values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46471991/ora-00913-too-many-values)

Answer (score 1):

You need to enumerate the target columns in the `insert` command, and accordingly `select` the relevant columns from the source table).

It looks like you want:

```
insert into kunde (adrnr, tmstmp, matchcode, art)
select n.adrnr, n.tmstmp, n.matchcode, n.art
from nag n
where not exists (select 1 from kunde k where n.adrnr = k.adrnr)
```

I rewrote the `left join ... where ... is null` as `not exists`, because I find that it is clearer - but the logic would be just he same with a `left join`.

Comment: I tried that but I got an error: ORA-04098 trigger SO:SAMPLE:TRIGGER is invalid and could not be confirmed again

You put (select 1 from kunde). What does 1 here do to the query?

Comment: @ella the error indicates that you have a trigger defined on the table and the trigger code is invalid. It shows the `insert` is working at least. `exists (select...)` is an existence check, it doesn't matter what it selects.

Comment: I deleted the triggers.

Now I tried to insert again using the following query: 
insert into kunde (adrnr, tmstmp, matchcode, art)
select NAG.adrnr, NAG.tmstmp, NAG.matchcode, NAG.art
from NAG
where not exists (select * from kunde where NAG.adrnr = kunde.adrnr)

And I get the following error: ORA-01400 insert NULL in ["SO", "KUNDE", "KNDNR"] not possible.

How do I fix it?

Comment: @ella It's saying you have to supply a value for the `kndnr` column. At the moment you only supply values for adrnr, tmstmp, matchcode, and art. I guess you need to add kndnr to the list. It sounds like an ID value (each row in kunde has a unique kndnr). Maybe there is a sequence defined. But this is drifting away from the original question, which I believe GMB has answered.